# Django GraphQL won't create new data with foreign key

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm new to Graphene, Django, and GraphQL and am trying to wrap my head around how it would work when updating tables that use a Foreign Key. I am able successfully create a new author, which does **not** require populating a foreign key field, but I cannot create a new book, which **does** require populating a foreign key field.

**My Question:** What is wrong with my implementation that is preventing me from creating a new book?

#### What is Happening

When I run the `CreateNewBook` mutation (shown below), GraphQL returns `null` as the title and no data is added to `dim_all_books`.

#### What I Expect

I expect that when I run the `CreateNewBook` mutation that the return results show the title of the book and a new record is appended to the table `dim_all_books`.

#### What I've Tried

When I run the following query, it works fine.

```
mutation CreateNewAuthor{
  createAuthor(authorData: {
    authorName: "William Shakespeare",
    yearBorn: "1722",
    yearDied: "1844",
    country: "Austria",
    booksWritten: 11
  }) {
    author {
      authorName
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run the following query immediately after that query, I get this result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createBook": {
      "book": null
    }
  }
}
```

```
mutation CreateNewBook {
  createBook(bookData: {
    title: "Romeo & Juliet",
    subtitle: "",
    authorName: "William Shakespeare",
    yearPublished: "1736",
    review: 3.2
  }) {
    book {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

This outcome occurs regardless of what value I put in for `authorName`.

#### Implementation

###### Project Creation

```bash
django-admin startproject core
python3 manage.py startapp books
python3 manage.py startapp authors
```

###### Books

```py
# books/models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(
        'authors.author',
        related_name='authors',
        verbose_name='author_name',
        db_column='author_name',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    year_published = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    review = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "dim_all_books"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
# books/schema.py
class BookType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'

class BookInputType(graphene.InputObjectType):
    title = graphene.String()
    subtitle = graphene.String()
    author_name = graphene.String()
    year_published = graphene.String()
    review = graphene.Float()

...

class CreateBook(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        book_data = BookInputType(required=True)

    book = graphene.Field(BookType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, book_data=None):
        book_instance = Book(
            title=book_data.title,
            subtitle=book_data.subtitle,
            author_name=book_data.author_name,
            year_published=book_data.year_published,
            review=book_data.review
        )
        book_instance.save()
        return CreateBook(book=book_instance)

...

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_book = CreateBook.Field()
    update_book = UpdateBook.Field()
    delete_book = DeleteBook.Field()
```

###### Authors

```py
# authors/models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        primary_key=True, 
        db_column='author_name',
        default='Unknown'
    )
    year_born = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    year_died = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    books_written = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'dim_all_authors'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
# authors/schema.py
class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class AuthorInputType(graphene.InputObjectType):
    author_name = graphene.String()
    year_born = graphene.String()
    year_died = graphene.String()
    country = graphene.String()
    books_written = graphene.Int()

...

class CreateAuthor(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        author_data = AuthorInputType(required=True)
    
    author = graphene.Field(AuthorType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, author_data=None):
        author_instance = Author(
            author_name = author_data.author_name,
            year_born = author_data.year_born,
            year_died = author_data.year_died,
            country = author_data.country,
            books_written = author_data.books_written
        )
        author_instance.save()
        
        return CreateAuthor(author=author_instance)

...

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
        create_author = CreateAuthor.Field()
        update_author = UpdateAuthor.Field()
        delete_author = DeleteAuthor.Field()
```

And then these schemas are set up in `core/schema.py` and `core.settings.py` as follows:

```py
# core/schema.py
import graphene
from authors.schema import Query as AuthorQuery
from authors.schema import Mutation as AuthorMutation
from books.schema import Query as BookQuery
from books.schema import Mutation as BookMutation

class Query(BookQuery, AuthorQuery):
    pass

class Mutation(BookMutation, AuthorMutation):
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

```py
# core/settings.py

...

GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA": "core.schema.schema"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you have to pass in the instance of the object that you want the foreign key to point to. In this example, I wanted `[dim_all_books].author_name` to point to `[dim_all_authors].author_name`. So, you can't just pass in "William Shakespear", but instead need to pass in the result of `Author.objects.get(pk=book_data.author_name)`. This required modifying my `books/schema.py` file as follows.

1. Add an import for the model(s) that your foreign key(s) references. In my case, this meant adding `from authors.models import Author` at the top of my file.
2. I had to update my mutation logic with the code below.

```py
class CreateBook(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        book_data = BookInput(required=True)

    book = graphene.Field(BookType)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, book_data=None):
        author = Author.objects.get(pk=book_data.author_name)
        book_instance = Book(
            title=book_data.title,
            subtitle=book_data.subtitle,
            author_name=author,
            year_published=book_data.year_published,
            review=book_data.review
        )
        book_instance.save()
        return CreateBook(book=book_instance)
```